# Login on Passport.js does not update on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am building my first full-stack MEAN application, but I was following an old tutorial but used a newer npm packages so some of my code doesn't work. I'm currently building a login/register app. My program does fine in registering a user, it stores it if the user hasn't been registered, and deny it if it already has. But when I login, it should change the angular view to logged in and add a logout button, but it doesn't seem to be doing so.

I used hashbang on my html, do I need to change something else in my code?

Here's the source code for the angular app

```
 app.controller('authController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location){
   $scope.user = {username: '', password: ''};
   $scope.error_message = '';

   $scope.login = function(){

     $http.post('/auth/login', $scope.user).then(function(data){
       if(data.state == 'success'){
         $rootScope.authenticated = true;
         console.log('user is now authenticated'); // not printing
         $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username;
         console.log('user is now logged in');
         $location.path('/');
         console.log('view is updated');
       }
       else{
         $scope.error_message = data.message;
       }
     });
   };

   $scope.register = function(){
     $http.post('/auth/signup', $scope.user).then(function(data){
       if(data.state == 'success'){
         $rootScope.authenticated = true;
         console.log('user is now authenticated'); //this is not printing
         $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username; //accessing mongodb
         console.log('user is now logged in');
         $location.path('/');
         console.log('view is updated');
       }
       else{
         $scope.error_message = data.message;
       }
     });
   };
 });
```

Here's the source for  the authentication route

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


 module.exports = function(passport){

     //sends successful login state back to angular
     router.get('/success', function(req, res){
         res.send({state: 'success', user: req.body.user ? req.body.user : null});
         console.log('successfully login');
     });

     //sends failure login state back to angular
     router.get('/failure', function(req, res){
         res.send({state: 'failure', user: null, message: "Invalid username or password"});
         console.log('username/password does not exist in database');
});

     //log in
     router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
         successRedirect: '/auth/success',
         failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'
     }));

     //sign up
     router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
         successRedirect: '/auth/success',
         failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'
     }));

     //log out
     router.get('/signout', function(req, res) {
         req.logout();
         res.redirect('/');
     });

     return router;

 }
```

UPDATE:

Is it maybe something to do with PassportJS?

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');   
 var User = mongoose.model('User');
 var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
 var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
 module.exports = function(passport){

// Passport needs to be able to serialize and deserialize users to support persistent login sessions
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializing user:',user.username);
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        console.log('deserializing user:',user.username);
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) { 
        // check in mongo if a user with username exists or not
        User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, 
            function(err, user) {
                // In case of any error, return using the done method
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                // Username does not exist, log the error and redirect back
                if (!user){
                    console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
                    return done(null, false);                 
                }
                // User exists but wrong password, log the error 
                if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                    console.log('Invalid Password');
                    return done(null, false); // redirect back to login page
                }
                // User and password both match, return user from done method
                // which will be treated like success
                return done(null, user);
            }
        );
    }
));

passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) {

        // find a user in mongo with provided username
        User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, function(err, user) {
            // In case of any error, return using the done method
            if (err){
                console.log('Error in SignUp: '+err);
                return done(err);
            }
            // already exists
            if (user) {
                console.log('User already exists with username: '+username);
                return done(null, false);
            } else {
                // if there is no user, create the user
                var newUser = new User();

                // set the user's local credentials
                newUser.username = username;
                newUser.password = createHash(password);

                // save the user
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err){
                        console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);  
                        throw err;  
                    }
                    console.log(newUser.username + ' Registration succesful');    
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
    })
);

var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
    return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
};
// Generates hash using bCrypt
var createHash = function(password){
    return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
};
};
```

Any help or general pointer will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't seem like any of this is related to angular. What's the issue client side?

Comment: I'm using hashbang, maybe that's it? I updated some of the source code above, it seems that it doesn't redirect me when I call          $location.path('/');

Comment: I'm using hashbang maybe that's it? @Phix dont think the stuff i have under $scope.register and $scope.login are executed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, don't think it's anything to do with the passportJS since the only thing I did there was hashing and checking password.